# How to integrate a function over a region $R$ with a single inequality?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

We've been given the following information:

$$R = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 :|x−1|+x\leq y\leq x+1\}$$

and we are asked to determine the exact value of the integral

$$\iint_{R} \cos (3 − y)^2\ dx\ dy.$$

I started by taking $0\leq y-x\leq 1$ since $|x-1|\geq 0$, 
and found $1-y\leq x \leq y$.

Using this I integrated with respect to $x$ and obtained the following integral:

$$\int_1^3 \cos (3 − y)^2 dy$$

Integrating this function results in a complex answer which I don't believe is correct as it is almost impossible to solve without an integral calculator. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I assume that by "complex answer" you mean a complicated answer, not one with complex numbers. :) OK, for starters, you should check that $0\le x\le 2$, because $|x-1|\le 1$.  You're just picking random algebra things here. You should work out the region *exactly*, and you'll find that it's a triangle with vertices at $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$, and $(2,3)$.

Comment: The answer contained complex numbers as well. Do you mean to say I have to integrate using the limits I find from graphing the function for x and y?

Comment: Complex numbers? No. No $\sqrt{-1}$'s involved here. As always, you should sketch the region of integration and the fact that you cannot find an antiderivative for this function suggests — as always — that you should change the order of integration.

Comment: I tried changing the order of integration but found a similar answer, I also sketched the region before I began changing the order and found the same triangle you described. On integrating the last integral in an online calculator I get 0.4614614624332164 + 5.950464648798916x10 ^(−66)i

Comment: Stop using a calculator and use your brain. This is all calculator round-off error. You get an elementary integral to do if you do this correctly. Edit your question to include the correct double integral and single integration, not the wrong stuff there.

Comment: @Enver Yes, it is. It works out perfectly when you integrate in the correct order. All such problems are made up that way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the correct double integral. I've written the same double integral I've been given

Comment: The boundary lines you have written in your question are just wrong. I agree that in the end we have $1\le y\le 3$. What are the limits on the $x$ integral? I found it easier to sketch the region by thinking in the other order, noting, as I said, that $0\le x\le 2$. Now what does $y$ do for fixed $x$?

Comment: @roguuu if it is still not resolved, you may want to edit your question with exact integral you get. $0.4614614624332164 + 5.950464648798916x10 ^(−66)i$ does not seem right. That is not what you should get when you integrate over the given triangular region.